# Setting Azure Redis SessionState provider for sub webconfig

Tags: azure, session, redis

My web app have two webconfig file like this

root
|
|-subsystem
  |web.config
web.config

Almost system had config use azure session ok, but my sub system cannot store session to azure. always null
I had copy same connection setting for sub webconfig file, but not work.

can you give me some advice

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is IIS version.

With dev environment IIS express not store session to redis. But my server with IIS 8.5 , it work!